# Dropdown icon in ToolbarAndroid + catching title tap event + search input (react native)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

So I am trying to set a normal, native android toolbar navigation with pretty standard behaviour... I seem to not be able to find examples or instructions in the DOCS how to make them

- **Dropdown icon in the title**

so, first thing to sort out would be the dropdown... I would like to have saying: May ^... (basically to display whatever icon after the title- possibly with custom margin) ...

couldn't find an example, but this is a pretty common practice

- **Catching the title tap event**

obviously I want then to open a calendar drop down, or whatever other action I want after the title has been tapped. There are onIconClicked  and onActionSelected events but not onTitleClicked event... any ideas?

- And finally..**Search box**

in the actions I have a 'search' icon, that ideally I want the search
   input box to appear in the toolbar (instead of the title)... again,
   pretty standard practice (similar to google play app or any other
   major app with material design)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is quite simple... leave the Title property empty

1. `<ToolbarAndroid ...> custom content </ToolbarAndroid>`
2. just wrap "custom content" in TouchableHighlight
3. Just put whatever you need in "custom content"